# Use XCode to build the ionic app again, but content isn't updated

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I was working on an ionic 4 app. When I finished adjusting, build the app for iOS again on VS Code, I switch to XCode and start building to test on my iPhone device.

But sometimes the app wasn't updated. The app I run on the browser on my laptop is the updated version, but the one finished building on my iPhone is not the updated one. Even changing the identifier won't work. (But sometimes it gets updated)

These are the code I was using for rebuilding on VSCode. After running that, I switch to XCode, adjust the signing setting and run building on my iPhone. I am sure the cookies and other temporary storage are not being used in the new app as I would need to log in again every time I build, and I use a unique identifier in every build to prevent that.

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios && 
ionic cordova platform add ios && 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

If anyone has encountered something similar, please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ionic deploy by any chance in your app?

Comment: @Bart I am using `platform add ios` to add the platform and then use XCode to build on it.